# How to check a combination of 3 keys pressed at same time c#

Tags: c#, keyboard, keypress

there is a posibility to check if 3 keys are pressed at the same time. For example "sdf" or we can only check for one at the time?

Comment: Why you need to check? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can check all the keys you need with `IsKeyDown` and the `&&` operator.

```
KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) && keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.F))
{
}
```

If you need to know which and how many keys are pressed at any moment `KeyboardState.GetPressedKeys()` will return you a `Keys` array.